# String,which repeats ,but not starts from the beginning in Java (diamond pattern

Tags: java, string, design-patterns

This is the work that i done so far:I have to print diamond pattern which always starts with uppercase from string, which repeats,but not always starts from the beginning.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = keyboard.next();
    userInput = Character.toUpperCase(userInput.charAt(0)) + userInput.substring(1);
    int i;
    int j;
    if (userInput.length() % 2 != 0) {

        for(i = 1; i < userInput.length(); i += 2) {
            for(j = 0; j < userInput.length() - 1 - i / 2; ++j) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for(j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
                System.out.print(userInput.charAt(j));
            }

            System.out.println("");
        }

        for(i = userInput.length(); i > 0; i -= 2) {
            for(j = 0; j < userInput.length() - 1 - i / 2; ++j) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for(j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
                System.out.print(userInput.charAt(j));
            }

            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    } else {
        for(i = 2; i < userInput.length(); i += 2) {
            for(j = 0; j < userInput.length() - 1 - i / 2; ++j) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for(j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
                System.out.print(userInput.charAt(j));
            }

            System.out.println("");
        }

        for(i = userInput.length(); i > 0; i -= 2) {
            for(j = 0; j < userInput.length() - 1 - i / 2; ++j) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for(j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
                System.out.print(userInput.charAt(j));
            }

            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }

}
```

For example my input is "Peter".
So my output is:

```
  P
 Pet
Peter
 Pet
  P
```

but it must be:

```
  P
 Ete
Rpete
 Rpe
  T
```

I dont know what to change to make this work

Comment: Can you give an example with a string that has an even number of letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a shorter version of your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String userInput = "Peter";
    int length = userInput.length();
    int m, j, i, n = 0;
    for (m = length % 2 > 0 ? 1 : 2; m < length * 2; m += 2) {
        i = m < length ? m : length * 2 - m;
        for (j = 0; j < length - 1 - i / 2; ++j) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for(j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            char c = userInput.charAt(n++ % length);
            c = j == 0 ? Character.toUpperCase(c) : Character.toLowerCase(c);
            System.out.print(c);
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You need some few changes:

1. Declare `int n=0;` after `int j;`
2. Always print `userInput.charAt(n++ % userInput.length())` instead of `charAt(j)`
3. In order to get only the first character in line in uppercase:

   ```
   char c = userInput.charAt(n++ % userInput.length());
   c = j == 0 ? Character.toUpperCase(c) : Character.toLowerCase(c);
   System.out.print(c);
   ```

Check the modulo operator.

With these changes, you'll get this output:

```
  P
 Ete
Rpete
 Rpe
  T
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that the input itself gets printed in a cylic manner, we can make use out of it. My proposal would be to concatenate the input string and print out the substrings which are determined by the structure of the diamond pattern.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = keyboard.next();
        String concatenated = userInput;

        // build up the index array
        int i, cumSum = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> helperIndex = new ArrayList<>();
        for(i = 1; i < userInput.length(); i += 2) {
            helperIndex.add(i);
            cumSum += i;
        }
        for(i = userInput.length(); i > 0; i -= 2) {
            helperIndex.add(i);
            cumSum += i;
        }
        int numOfWordRepitition = cumSum / userInput.length() ;
        for (i = 0; i < numOfWordRepitition; i++){
            concatenated += userInput;
        }

        // print out diamond
        String substr;
        int prev = helperIndex.get(0);
        int next = helperIndex.get(0);
        substr = concatenated.substring(0 , helperIndex.get(0));
        System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(substr.charAt(0)) + substr.substring(1));
        for(i = 1; i < userInput.length(); i++){
            next += helperIndex.get(i);
            substr = concatenated.substring(prev , next);
            substr = Character.toUpperCase(substr.charAt(0)) + substr.substring(1);
            System.out.println(substr);
            prev = next;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Nice answer, upvoted. But your answer is slightly deviated from OP's desired output. OP's desired output shows the Title case in the output, but your one doesn't do so for all the lines. Try to fix this.